# Missing hyperref.cfg file

Tags: hyperref, miktex, missing

I use MiKTeX and recently I have updated my packages. And now I have a problem. Suppose that I compile a LaTeX file which uses the `hyperref` package, such as this one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
A
\end{document}
```

Then I get a message saying: `The required file`

`tex/latex/00miktex\hyperref.cfg`

`is missing. It is a part of the following package`

`miktex-latex`

However:

1. That package **is** installed in my system.
2. Uninstalling and re-installing it changes nothing.
3. There is indeed no `hyperref.cfg` file at that location.

Any suggestion about what I should do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

hyperref.cfg has been removed from miktex (at the request of the hyperref maintainer).

But your package database is not up-to-date and so miktex is still looking for it.

Go to the miktex console (admin and user mode), in the menu tasks you find an entry to update the package database.

[image]